# How to calculate button counts of a HTML page?

Tags: html

I have a HTML page, source code is given below -

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsMeth() {
        alert('Count of buttons : '+document.getElementsByTagName('button').length);
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="button 1" id="btn1" name="btn1" /><br>
<input type="button" value="butto 2" id="btn2" name="btn2" /><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate button count" id="btn3" name="btn3" onclick="jsMeth();"/>
</html>
```

My basic purpose is, when I click on button having id "btn3", it should display number of buttons in my HTML page (in this case 3). But somehow it is always showing 0.

---

Thanks for your quick reply. As all of you suggested, I have modified my code as shown below -

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsMeth() {
        alert('Count of buttons : '+document.querySelectorAll('[type=button]').length);
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="button 1" id="btn1" name="btn1" /><br>
<input type="button" value="butto 2" id="btn2" name="btn2" /><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate button count" id="btn3" name="btn3" onclick="jsMeth();"/>
</html>
```

But now I am getting below error -

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 4
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/556996/Desktop/demohtml.html
```

I am testing in IE8. Please help!

Thanks,
Kartic

Comment: The tag name for all of those elements is `input`.

Comment: Yes Brian, I can use document.getElementByTagName("input") and then check for type button, but I was wondering if I could get all button elements without doing all these stuffs. Now I doubt there is no option for that. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this...

```
function jsMeth() {
        alert('Count of buttons : '+document.querySelectorAll('[type=button]').length);
}
```

Or this for old browsers

```
function jsMeth() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var numBts = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
        if(elem[i].getAttribute('type') === 'button'){
           numBts+=1; 
        }
    }
    alert(numBts);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PbEdY/3/)**

Comment: Hi MG_Bautista,

Thanks for your reply. As I have already posted, using document.querySelectorAll('[type=button]').length I am getting javascript error. Also, it does't work in older versions of IE (IE7 and older). Can you please please any other solutions.

Comment: @Kartic My friend, see the aswer again... the demo is updated

Comment: That's cool. I have already tried this. But I must say, This is the best solution as far as I tried. Thanks++ you

Answer (score 3):

Try using either of

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')
```

or the more specific

```
document.querySelectorAll('[type=button'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that you don't have any elements with the tag name `button`.  All of your buttons have the tag name `input`.

If you aren't supporting IE7, you could use `querySelectorAll` to get those elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]')
```

Or you could change your HTML to use `<button>` elements:

```
<button type="button" value="button 1" id="btn1" name="btn1">button 1</button>
```